# Iterate over CSV file and run await for each row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I want to iterate over a CSV file in node, and for each row, call an asynchronous function and wait for it to complete.

How can I do this?

I have:

```
const getFile = async function(url) {
    const response = await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    const ad = await page.waitForSelector('div.chart');
    await ad.screenshot({
        path: path
    });
};

fs.createReadStream(fname)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        let id = row.ad_id;
        let url = 'xxxx' + id;
        await getFile(path);
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
```

But this gives me `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, throwing the error on the `await getFile(path);` line.

Comment: you need to make the callback function async -> `.on('data', async (row) => {...`

Comment: Thanks, if I change that I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 542)` but perhaps that's something to do with my `getFile` function not being right?

Comment: making the callback function async will not cause the pipe to pause until the returned promise resolves

Comment: What _should_ I be doing instead? So confused :(

Comment: @Richard Please see the answer I posted and let us know if it worked. :)

Comment: If what you want to do is know when all the rows functions finished, you can use the [Promise.all](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/) function so you can make the row handler async and have a wait inside of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a SyntaxError because, as it says, `await` is only valid in an `async` function. You can fix this by making your callback `async`, but that alone won't cause the pipe to stop emitting further `data` events until the async function finishes. You can probably, however, do this manually like so:

```
const csvPipe = fs.createReadStream(fname).pipe(csv());
csvPipe.on('data', async (row) => {
        csvPipe.pause();
        let id = row.ad_id;
        let url = 'xxxx' + id;
        await getFile(path);
        csvPipe.resume();
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `getFile` function is already a promise, you can pause and resume the pipe using the promise functions and without making the function async.

```js
const csvPipe = fs.createReadStream(fname).pipe(csv());
csvPipe.on('data', (row) => {
    csvPipe.pause();
    let id = row.ad_id;
    let url = 'xxxx' + id;
    getFile(path).finally(() => csvPipe.resume());
}).on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
});
```